# Rails avoid blocking worker in slow controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-5

Generally any DB/File IO even external HTTP requests are pretty quick, but I am finding slower ones can hold up all my workers (and memory limits how many Ruby instances I can run), and creating large numbers of threads per worker has other issues (with CPU or memory heavy actions clogging up the system).

Can I have Rails process these actions in an async manner (more like NodeJS) or else introduce threads for that action in some way?

Since I want to respond to the original request, neither workers or just spawning another thread myself seems appropriate, since Rails will ensure the original thread sends a response when it returns from the controller.

```
def my_action
  @data1 = get_data("https://slow.com/data") #e.g. Net::HTTP
  @data2 = get_data("https://slow.com/data2?group_id=#{@data["id"]}")
  render
end


def my_action
  get_data("https://slow.com/data").then do |data1| # e.g. internal thread, not sure on other options
    get_data("https://slow.com/data2?group_id=#{data["id"]}").then do |data2|
      @data1 = data1
      @data2 = data2
      render # Appears to have no effect
    end
  end
  # Rails does an implicit "render" on return
end

def my_action
  Thread.new do # explicit thread just for this request
    @data1 = get_data("https://slow.com/data")
    @data2 = get_data("https://slow.com/data2?group_id=#{@data["id"]}")
    render
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not use a background jobs, [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) e.g.?

Comment: And how does the background job respond to the original HTTP request? I dont want to have to add polling, websockets, or such to the client-side, just not kill the server if there is several 500 to 1000ms slow IO-bound requests

Comment: Asyn jobs can't respond to http request. It's all about application architecture, if request to your application spawn another request and IO freez, that's not a good application design.

Answer (score 1):

In a Rails application, you're better off relying on an external process to run background jobs rather than using Ruby Threads.

[Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is a pretty standard gem now for this purpose.

Comment: How does that allow the background job to respond to the original HTTP request? Seems an entirely different use case, either were the client does not care, or its slow enough the client side can poll for it?

Comment: Rails isn't an async framework like node. You can see if ActionCable will do what you want, but you may need to rethink the architecture of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So potentially slow actions need to be designed to use polling or websockets instead so the work can be offloaded outside Rails (or at least the web workers)? Id really like to avoid that as generally API designs and client side frameworks dont expect that (e.g. using an XHR to populate a table)

Comment: Actually, polling at such a high rate would likely be counterproductive, these actions I was thinking of really are about 500ms total most of the time, maybe 10 seconds worst case if the user has a particular heavy dataset (which is processed by that other server anyway so not my CPU load). Just that I found occasionally they held up all my processes/threads with a big queue of blocking requests...

Answer (score 0):

If it takes 10 seconds to process a request, and you want to send your response to the original HTTP request, then you've got to hold open that HTTP connection for 10 seconds. You can't get around that. If your server can handle X HTTP connections, and you have X+1 people making these slow requests... someone **is** going to get blocked.

There are only three possible solutions:

- Figure out a way to process the requests faster. This is ideal, if you can do it.
- Don't hold open the HTTP connection. Run a background task (using Sidekiq or similar gem) to do the work. When it's done, send it via websocket, or have the client poll for it. It makes your API more complicated for the client, but as a client I'd rather deal with a little complexity than having my requests blocked and maybe time out.
- Scale up your server until it can handle the traffic. This is the "throw money at the problem" solution. I generally disapprove of this, since you'll have to keep throwing more money every time demand grows. But if your organization has more money than dev time, it might work for a while.

Those are your options.